# WebSecurity.ResetPassword unable to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC4 application and i am using default membership. I have changed UserId from int to Bigint. When i call WebSecurity.ResetPassword with token and new password it is showing error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Source Error:

   Dim newpassw As String = mdl.Password
   Dim response As Boolean = WebSecurity.ResetPassword(mdl.PasswordResetToken, newpassw)
```

When i changed UserId from Bigint to int its working fine.
 But i need Bigint instead of int for UserId in database. How to do Websecurity.ResetPassword for Bigint?